# are constants type declaration case sensitive in HLASM?

Tags: assembly, mainframe, zos

Is there a difference for using lower or uppercase C when declaring a constant char ?

```
FIELD1       DCL      C'1'
FIELD2       DCL      c'1'
```

Code runs as if it made no difference, but I see no mention of it in the [documentation](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ent.asm.zos.doc/topics/fn1lrmst126.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, HLASM is case-insensitive.  You can, of course, have mixed-case literal strings (*e.g.*, `C'Hello world'`), but labels (*e.g.*, `Field` and `FIELD1`) and keywords (*e.g.* `DCL` and `dcl`) are not case-sensitive.